# AWS ECS execute-command ... ""/bin/sh" doesn't error but doesn't start up a shell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to ssh/connect to my container via the ecs execute  command

This is the complete command I'm running

```
aws --region us-west-2 ecs execute-command --cluster .... --task ... --container ...  --interactive --command "/bin/sh"
```

This command doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't open up a shell to the container. It gives no output.

Does anyone have any suggestions for debugging this?

Comment: Yea it's unconventional but I don't think that's the issue. It's fine for region to be in front. For example this runs fine - (aws --region us-west-2 s3 ls)

Comment: Are you sure you want "ecs" and not "ec2" ?

Comment: yes it's a ecs container

Comment: Strange .... maybe add the `--debug` option and see if you get any output

Comment: @Jamie_D This command has no output lol - "This command produces no output.

" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/execute-command.html.

Comment: I found the solution. Will update this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ecs execute-command doesn't give any [output](https://%5B1%5D:%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/execute-command.html)

but to debug this kind of issue further, you can run
this ECS [checker](https://github.com/aws-containers/amazon-ecs-exec-checker) - https://github.com/aws-containers/amazon-ecs-exec-checker

After I ran this, I determined that the session manager plugin was installed incorrectly